# how to assign random number with range to 2D array dimensions

Tags: java, arrays

In main, assign 2 random numbers (ints between 3 and 10) for the first dimension and the second dimension

I had this but the Math.random() method doesn;t work

```
import java.lang.Math;


public class Homework2 {
public static void main(String[] args){

    double doubMatrix1[][] = (int) (Math.random()*(10-3+1)+3);
    double doubMatrix2[][];
    double doubMatrix3[][];


}
}
```

Comment: "it didn't work" what do you mean by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to initialize a matrix of double with an int

Types must be equals!

Here are your code fixed.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Homework2 {
public static void main(String[] args){

    int d1 = (int) (Math.random()*(10-3+1)+3);
    int d2 = (int) (Math.random()*(10-3+1)+3);

    double doubMatrix1[][] = new double[d1][d2];
    double doubMatrix2[][];
    double doubMatrix3[][];


}
}
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

To create a multidimensional array in Java, use `new <type>[dim1][dim2]`, as in the following code:

```
Random rand = new Random();

int r1 = rand.nextInt(8) + 3;
int r2 = rand.nextInt(8) + 3;
double doubMatrix[][] = new double[r1][r2];
```

Comment: im not sure but according to my professor i was supposed to use this to assign random int (int)(Math.random()*(MAX-MIN+1)+MIN)

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns fraction between 0.0 and 1.0. So with `(int) (Math.random()*(10-3+1)+3)` you are getting only one random number between 3 and 10 inclusive. But you are assigning it to `double doubMatrix1[][]`. So probably you are calling constructor in wrong way. You are supposed to generate two distinct random number `r1, r2` according to the method taught by your teacher then call constructor like `double doubMatrix1[][] = double[r1][r2]`

Answer (score 0):

check this out, this might be helpful:

```
// DMA of 2D array in C++
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x = 3, y = 3;

int **ptr = new int *[x];

for(int i = 0; i<y; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = new int[y];
}
srand(time(0));

for(int j = 0; j<x; j++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k<y; k++)
    {
        int a = rand()%5;
        ptr[j][k] = a;
        cout<<ptr[j][k]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}
```

we used a pointer and deal it just like 2D array here, use % for limit